# How to use external jar library in a SAP HANA XS project

Tags: java, hana, hana-xs

I am trying to make an XS project in HANA which will use some of the classes and methods that can be found in a .jar file. These classes and methods will do some calculations and present it to the user in the UI.

The question is: How do I access methods and classes of that .jar file?

I have registered it as an external library, but I have no idea how to call it from my XS javascript source files.

Answer (score 2):

there's no way to invoke external .jar package from XS's server-side JavaScript. You can use an external library using function "$.import", but this is only valid for JavaScript library.

Answer (score 2):

XS Server does not and will not support Java. Only Javascript...

Comment: You said that because of the `java` tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to outsource some of your xsjs functions to an external library, xsengine provides a special format for this, called "**.xsjslib**".
You can import a library using the following code:

```
$.import("<package_your_library_was_deployed>","yourLib");
```

access functions inside your lib by this path:

```
$.path.to.your.library.filename.yourFunction();
```

Comment: Can you please explain this with an example. I'm facing issues with importing even the existing packages like util.